# Android: Start a thread in a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

i want to start a new thread in my own service which is started from an activity. In this thread I want to update data in a database after every 3 seconds. I created the databse and initializes it in my onStartCommand() method. Where should I implement my Thread and how?

I tried this but it didn't work, the app will be unfortunately closed. Without the call of this method everything works fin.

I create this method, which i called in my onStartCommand

```
private void startThreadUpdatingDatabase(){
    Log.d("Database", "startThreadUpdatingDatabase(was called)");
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run(){
            //do stuff
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: read damn stacktrace if your app crashes! And what the point you need for a thread really?

Comment: no need for a Thread for such "no long" operation,  did you try a Handler?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace from logcat to your question. Threads work fine in Services, and they really don't care about each other. Doing database operations is nothing you should do in the main thread, so there is a point in doing that in a thread. You could consider an IntentService which is a Service that launches a thread for you. They are not exactly great for 3 second repeating tasks but work.

Comment: Don't be so harsh people. Read this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingAService

Comment: I'm new in developing sorry. In this service I add some listener to get livedata from a car. This works. In this listeners I calculate some informations from the livedata. And I am looking for a way writing these informations in my database. So that I can read this calculated informations from activitys.

Comment: I fixed the problem, that the app was unfortunately closed. @Toguard I read this site already. But how can i change my thread code above that it is execute every about 3 seconds?

Comment: You should post logcat if you have a crash. Also, you ask a new question in the comments - that should be posted to a new question. (Even so - look at "timers" in Android.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start a recurring task you can try different approaches:

1) Alarm 
2) Handler 
3) TimerTask (My least favorite)

**Alarm**:

```
private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
private static final long ALARM_INTERVAL = 3 * 60 * 1000;

private void issueAlarm() {
    if(mAlarmManager == null)
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int) ALARM_INTERVAL);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), ALARM_INTERVAL, alarmIntent);
}
```

Create your AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Do DB Stuff here
    }

}
```

And do not forget to register it in the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false" />
```

**Handler**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
    // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
    // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
    // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
        Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
}
```

And queue up your postedTask

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //As danny117 pointed out, multiple clients starting the service
    //Can trigger this.
    mServiceHandler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable);
    mServiceHandler.post(yourRunnable);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Runnable should look like:

```
private Runnable yourRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
        //DB work here
        if(mServiceHandler != null)
            mServiceHandler.postDelayed(this, ALARM_INTERVAL);
        }
}
```

Also clean up after service stops:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mServiceHandler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable);
    mServiceLooper.quit();
}
```

**Timer**:

Create your Timer:

```
private Timer myTimer = new Timer();
```

Create the recurring Timer Task:

```
private void scheduleTask() {
    myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            //Do DB stuff here
        }
    }, 0, ALARM_INTERVAL);
}
```

References:

[Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)
[Creating a Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingAService)

Comment: You could get multiples running in the above code because onStartCommand can get called more than once.  The solution for this caveat is  handler.removeCallback(youRunnable) then handler.post(youRunnable).

Comment: Nice observation, just made the change.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat with a delay you make a runnable that calls postDelayed of a handler to restart it after a set time period.

```
//change the notificationSmallIcon (titlebar) so it flashes every few seconds
private static Runnable iconWarnRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isWarningRunning) {
            long dely;
            if (notificationSmallIcon == R.drawable.ic_launcher2) {
                notificationSmallIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher2x;
                dely = iconWarnDelay1;
            } else {
                notificationSmallIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher2;
                dely = iconWarnDelay2;
            }
            notifyHandler.postDelayed(this, dely);
            myShowNotification();
        } else {
            //just in nick of time
            notificationSmallIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher2;
        }
    }
};

final HandlerThread myThread = new HandlerThread("myHandlerThread");
private static long iconWarnDelay1;
private static long iconWarnDelay2;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    iconWarnDelay1 = 2500;
    iconWarnDelay2 = 500;
    myThread.start();
    myThread.setPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    notifyHandler = new Handler(myThread.getLooper());
```

... somewhere you start the runnable it's really important that when you start you remove first so you always have just one running.

```
isWarningRunning = true;
notifyHandler.removeCallbacks(iconWarnRunnable);
notifyHandler.postDelayed(iconWarnRunnable, iconWarnDelay1);
```

... somewhere stop the runnable

```
isWarningRunning = false;
notifyHandler.removeCallbacks(iconWarnRunnable);
```